# dimensions conflict when trying to use a pretrained wav2vec2-xls-r-300m model

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface

i am trying to use a pretrained model facebook/wav2vec2-xls-r-300m and fine tune it for audio classification and more specifically emotion recognition. i am using an audio labeled dataset ( 12 labels )

model conf:

MAX_DURATION = 5
SAMPLING_RATE = 16000
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_CLASSES = 12
HIDDEN_DIM = 768
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = MAX_DURATION * SAMPLING_RATE  # Maximum length of the input audio file.

MAX_FRAMES = 49
MAX_EPOCHS = 2

MODEL_CHECKPOINT = "facebook/wav2vec2-xls-r-300m"  # Name of pretrained model from Hugging Face Model

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor

config = {
    "do_normalize": True,
    "feature_extractor_type": "Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor",
    "feature_size": 1,
    "padding_side": "right",
    "padding_value": 0,
    "return_attention_mask": True,
    "sampling_rate": 16000
}


# Initialize the feature extractor
feature_extractor = Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(MODEL_CHECKPOINT, **config)
 
# Define your preprocess function
def preprocess_function(examples):
    audio_arrays = [x["array"] for x in examples["audio"]]
    inputs = feature_extractor(
        audio_arrays,
        max_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
        truncation=True,
        padding=True,
    )
    return inputs
classification head :


from transformers import TFWav2Vec2Model


def mean_pool(hidden_states, feature_lengths):
    attenion_mask = tf.sequence_mask(
        feature_lengths, maxlen=MAX_FRAMES, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64
    )
    padding_mask = tf.cast(
        tf.reverse(tf.cumsum(tf.reverse(attenion_mask, [-1]), -1), [-1]),
        dtype=tf.dtypes.bool,
    )
    hidden_states = tf.where(
        tf.broadcast_to(
            tf.expand_dims(~padding_mask, -1), (BATCH_SIZE, MAX_FRAMES, HIDDEN_DIM)
        ),
        0.0,
        hidden_states,
    )
    pooled_state = tf.math.reduce_sum(hidden_states, axis=1) / tf.reshape(
        tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.cast(padding_mask, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32), axis=1),
        [-1, 1],
    )
    return pooled_state


class TFWav2Vec2ForAudioClassification(layers.Layer):
    """Combines the encoder and decoder into an end-to-end model for training."""

    def __init__(self, model_checkpoint, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        # Instantiate the Wav2Vec 2.0 model without the Classification-Head
        self.wav2vec2 = TFWav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained(
            model_checkpoint, apply_spec_augment=False, from_pt=True
        )
        self.pooling = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        # Drop-out layer before the final Classification-Head
        self.intermediate_layer_dropout = layers.Dropout(0.5)
        # Classification-Head
        self.final_layer = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, inputs):
        # We take only the first output in the returned dictionary corresponding to the
        # output of the last layer of Wav2vec 2.0
        hidden_states = self.wav2vec2(inputs["input_values"])[0]

        # If attention mask does exist then mean-pool only un-masked output frames
        if tf.is_tensor(inputs["attention_mask"]):
            # Get the length of each audio input by summing up the attention_mask
            # (attention_mask = (BATCH_SIZE x MAX_SEQ_LENGTH) ∈ {1,0})
            audio_lengths = tf.cumsum(inputs["attention_mask"], -1)[:, -1]
            # Get the number of Wav2Vec 2.0 output frames for each corresponding audio input
            # length
            feature_lengths = self.wav2vec2.wav2vec2._get_feat_extract_output_lengths(
                audio_lengths
            )
            pooled_state = mean_pool(hidden_states, feature_lengths)
        # If attention mask does not exist then mean-pool only all output frames
        else:
            pooled_state = self.pooling(hidden_states)

        intermediate_state = self.intermediate_layer_dropout(pooled_state)
        final_state = self.final_layer(intermediate_state)

        return final_state

**model**

def build_model():
    # Model's input
    inputs = {
        "input_values": tf.keras.Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="float32"),
        "attention_mask": tf.keras.Input(shape=(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="int32"),
    }
    # Instantiate the Wav2Vec 2.0 model with Classification-Head using the desired
    # pre-trained checkpoint
    wav2vec2_model = TFWav2Vec2ForAudioClassification(MODEL_CHECKPOINT, NUM_CLASSES)(
        inputs
    )
    # Model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, wav2vec2_model)
    # Loss
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    # Optimizer
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
    # Compile and return
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model


model = build_model()
```

i got this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-b7f377675faf> in <cell line: 23>()
     21 
     22 
---> 23 model = build_model()

4 frames
/tmp/__autograph_generated_filejjrdimiv.py in tf__mean_pool(hidden_states, feature_lengths)
     10                 attenion_mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).sequence_mask, (ag__.ld(feature_lengths),), dict(maxlen=ag__.ld(MAX_FRAMES), dtype=ag__.ld(tf).dtypes.int64), fscope)
     11                 padding_mask = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reverse, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cumsum, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reverse, (ag__.ld(attenion_mask), [-1]), None, fscope), -1), None, fscope), [-1]), None, fscope),), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).dtypes.bool), fscope...
---> 12                 hidden_states = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).where, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).broadcast_to, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).expand_dims, (~ag__.ld(padding_mask), -1), None, fscope), (ag__.ld(BATCH_SIZE), ag__.ld(MAX_FRAMES), ag__.ld(HIDDEN_DIM))), None, fscope), 0.0, ag__.ld(hidden_states)), None, fscope)
     13                 pooled_state = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.reduce_sum, (ag__.ld(hidden_states),), dict(axis=1), fscope) / ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.reduce_sum, (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.ld(padding_mask),), dict(dtype=ag__.ld(tf).dtypes.float32), fscope),), dict(axis=0...
     14                 try:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification" (type TFWav2Vec2ForAudioClassification).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-31-474bb7233250>", line 56, in call  *
        pooled_state = mean_pool(hidden_states, feature_lengths)
    File "<ipython-input-31-474bb7233250>", line 12, in mean_pool  *
        hidden_states = tf.where(

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 49 and 249 for '{{node tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification/SelectV2}} = SelectV2[T=DT_FLOAT](tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification/BroadcastTo, tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification/SelectV2/t, tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification/tf_wav2_vec2_model/wav2vec2/encoder/layer_norm/batchnorm/add_1)' with input shapes: [32,49,768], [], [?,249,1024].


Call arguments received by layer "tf_wav2_vec2_for_audio_classification" (type TFWav2Vec2ForAudioClassification):
  • inputs={'input_values': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 80000), dtype=float32)', 'attention_mask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 80000), dtype=int32)'}
```

i am using the EdwardLin2023/ASVP_ESD from hugging face , where i found this exact tutorial on how to finetune a facebook/wav2vec2-base on audio classification and since the model i am using facebook/wav2vec2-xls-r-300m is based on wav2vec2 i didnt change any parameters

heres the config of the model i am using as instructed in huggingface

````
{
  "do_normalize": true,
  "feature_extractor_type": "Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor",
  "feature_size": 1,
  "padding_side": "right",
  "padding_value": 0,
  "return_attention_mask": true,
  "sampling_rate": 16000
}

{
  "activation_dropout": 0.0,
  "apply_spec_augment": true,
  "architectures": [
    "Wav2Vec2ForPreTraining"
  ],
  "attention_dropout": 0.1,
  "bos_token_id": 1,
  "codevector_dim": 768,
  "contrastive_logits_temperature": 0.1,
  "conv_bias": true,
  "conv_dim": [
    512,
    512,
    512,
    512,
    512,
    512,
    512
  ],
  "conv_kernel": [
    10,
    3,
    3,
    3,
    3,
    2,
    2
  ],
  "conv_stride": [
    5,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2,
    2
  ],
  "ctc_loss_reduction": "sum",
  "ctc_zero_infinity": false,
  "diversity_loss_weight": 0.1,
  "do_stable_layer_norm": true,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "feat_extract_activation": "gelu",
  "feat_extract_dropout": 0.0,
  "feat_extract_norm": "layer",
  "feat_proj_dropout": 0.1,
  "feat_quantizer_dropout": 0.0,
  "final_dropout": 0.0,
  "gradient_checkpointing": false,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 1024,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 4096,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-05,
  "layerdrop": 0.1,
  "mask_feature_length": 10,
  "mask_feature_prob": 0.0,
  "mask_time_length": 10,
  "mask_time_prob": 0.075,
  "model_type": "wav2vec2",
  "num_attention_heads": 16,
  "num_codevector_groups": 2,
  "num_codevectors_per_group": 320,
  "num_conv_pos_embedding_groups": 16,
  "num_conv_pos_embeddings": 128,
  "num_feat_extract_layers": 7,
  "num_hidden_layers": 24,
  "num_negatives": 100,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "proj_codevector_dim": 768,
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.12.0.dev0",
  "use_weighted_layer_sum": false
}

```
````